# Kotlin cast from LinkedHashMap<String, String> to String?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm parsing a very simple YAML file.

Here is my code:

```
val yaml = Yaml()
val inputStream: InputStream = FileInputStream("permissions.yml")
val obj = yaml.load<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>(inputStream)
println(obj.get("accepted_groups")) // prints [A, B]
val group = obj.get("accepted_groups") // crashes
```

The error is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
So how does println manage to print the object? How can I retrieve an Array from this LinkedHashMap?

Comment: How can I retrieve an Array from this LinkedHashMap?

Comment: The actual value associated to the accepted_groups is an ArrayList. But you're told the Kotlin compiler that yaml.load() would return a LinkedHashMap<String, String>, containing Strings as values. So the compiler inserts a cast to String, hence the exception. You need to provide the correct generic type.

Comment: yamlLoad() returns a LinkedHashMap.         val inputStream: InputStream = FileInputStream("permissions.yml")
        val obj = yaml.load<ArrayList<String>>(inputStream) gives the error class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Although @AlexeyRomanov says there are no casts in the code. So how is it a ClassCastException?

Comment: It returns a Map. But the **values** inside the Map are not Strings as you claim. At least one of them is a List.

Comment: Yes, that was wrong. Of course there is a cast thanks to type erasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the values in your YAML file aren't (all) strings. I.e. it looks something like

```
accepted_groups:
    - A
    - B
```

not

```
accepted_groups: "[A, B]"
```

So `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` is simply the wrong type to use. 
What is the right type, can't be said without knowing:

1. the actual structure of the file;
2. which library `Yaml` class comes from (it isn't Kotlin standard library, or Spring Boot which you mention in tags).

`LinkedHashMap<String, Any>` will probably work, but isn't the best choice.

> So how does println manage to print the object?

By calling `toString`, as it does for any object.

The problem with

```
val group = obj.get("accepted_groups")
```

is that by using `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` the type inferred for `group` is `String` but the actual value stored there isn't.